# Assembly SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, intel

I have 4 variables in SEGMENT .DATA

1. Array A
2. Array B
3. Array C
4. Arrays size

My goal is to multiply i-th element of A with i-th element of B and the result goes to i-th element of array C.

I am using SASM with NASM compiler, intel x86

here is my code:

```
%include "io.inc"

SECTION .DATA
    A DD 10, 200, -34, 56, 7
    B DD 12, -3, 4, 7, 100
    C DD 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    SIZE DB 5

section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    MOV ESI, 0
    MOV ECX, [SIZE]
    MULT:
        MOV EAX, [A + ESI*4]
        MOV EBX, [B + ESI*4]
        IMUL EAX, EBX
        MOV [C + ESI*4], EAX; Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
        INC ESI
        LOOP MULT
        xor eax, eax
    ret
```

any ideas what the issue might be ?

Comment: thanks that worked, can your put you comment as an answer ?

Comment: `MOV ECX, [SIZE]` is wrong, the size is defined as `SIZE DB 5` = byte, not dword, so you either should change the instruction to `movzx ecx, byte [SIZE]`, or the definition to `SIZE DD 5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have *SASM*, but the instruction in qustion looks okay. The only reason I can think of is that the destination `[C + ESI*4]` is in a read only section. At this point I noticed that you define the data in a section called `.DATA` with this line:

```
SECTION .DATA
```

I don't know what SASM uses for linker scripts but likely the `.DATA` section is not the typical name for the read/write section and likely lead to the linker creating the executable with `.DATA` being readonly. The read/write section is usually called `.data` (lowercase matters). Try modifying `SECTION .DATA` to read:

```
SECTION .data
```